# ArcGis Runtime SDK for .Net - keep feature in the middle of the screen

Tags: arcgis-10.2, map-drawing, graphics, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

i'm working with ArcGis Runtime 10.2.5 SDK for .Net.

I want to keep a graphic in the middle of the screen no matter what happens in basemap. I want to simulate an aircraft flying over the map, keeping it pinned at the center and updating basemap envelope.

My first approach was update both basemap envelope and aircraft geometry with same the position, but since the procedures don't execute at same time

```
    //first basemap is centered
    MapPoint center = new MapPoint(aircraft.longitude, aircraft.latitude, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
    MapView.SetView(center);
    //after that, aircraft is centered
    draw_aircraft(center.X, center.Y);
```

there are some "vibrations" when zoom is near to earth (where low difference in geo coordinates means big differences in pixels).

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add the aircraft graphic at the center of the map and simply keep it there. As you update the center of the map extent, the graphic at the center will accurately represent the aircraft location without being updated.

Comment: This is a pretty basic thing to do.  If you have to update the coordinates of the graphic as new coordinates come in, it is just as easy to adjust your map's extent.  You have to check your options for zooming to an area or changing extent, but you should find what you need.